# Notation for vectors that exclude zero

Tags: notation

Is there a conventional notation for the set of all vectors of length $n$ such that not one element of the vector is equal to zero?

Right now I have to write out something like "vector $B$ blah blah blah, where

$B \not\in \left\{A =[a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n], \textrm{ where } \forall i, a_i \neq 0 \right\}$.

I'm wondering if there is a more compact/conventional way to express this?

Comment: I don't know of any widely spread convention for that. If you like you might write $\Pi_1^n a_i \not= 0$, dunno if you find it any nicer than what you wrote

Comment: $(a_1,..,a_n)\in(K^\times)^n$ where $K$ is the coefficient field, is another possibility.

Comment: How about $(a_i)_{i = 1}^n \in (K^\times)^n$?

Comment: What are the coordinates good for? Why not just $A ≠ 0$?